# Right word for a person who makes comments to another person habits when they have there own habits

Tags: meaning

What's the right word for a person who makes a comment towards another person habits, but they have their own habits?

Comment: Word it be hypercrit

Comment: I feel like this could use more details. I also thought of "micromanager" because your example is kind of vague. What kind of habits and comments are these? Could you provide a concrete example? You can [edit] your post to include more details.

Comment: This definitely needs an edit: do you mean the *same* habits (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_7:5), or different ones?

Answer (score 1):

> **hypocrite** someone who says they have particular moral beliefs but behaves in way that shows these are not sincere.  [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hypocrite)

The abstract noun is **hypocrisy**, the adjective is **hypocritical**.

A few examples:

- "we dislike hypocrites more than people who are straightforwardly awful"  [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2017/feb/10/why-everyone-hates-a-hypocrite-oliver-burkeman)
- "Sure, politicians are notorious for their hypocrisy."  [The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2017/06/mind-of-a-hypocrite/530958/)
- "The End of Hypocrisy: American Foreign Policy in the Age of Leaks" (Article title) [Foreign Affairs](https://www.foreignaffairs.com/articles/united-states/2013-10-15/end-hypocrisy)
- "When Tom finds out that Daisy is having
  an affair of her own, his reaction is nothing but hypocritical." [Essay](https://msu.edu/~delapmat/gatsby2.htm) about *The Great Gatsby* at Michigan State University.

Comment: A good answer, but it would be nice to see some examples of how it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Hypocrite is probably the word you're thinking of. In this context, it means a person who displays a false appearance of virtue.

For your example, a relevant idiom is "the pot calling the kettle black". It is used when one person is accusing or blaming another, when in truth both people are guilty.